# php strange behaviour accessing array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a function returning an array, called curPageURL. On my local apache, I accessed the return-value of the Page like this: `$pageUrl = explode('?',curPageURL())[0];` it worked pretty fine. But on live it didn't work. It took me a lot of time to figure out, that the error was accessing the array.

This solved the issue:

```
$pageUrl = explode('?',curPageURL());
$pageURL = pageURL[0];


function curPageURL() {
        $pageURL = 'http';
        if (isset($_SERVER["HTTPS"]) && $_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
        $pageURL .= "://";
        if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
            $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
        } else {
            $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
        }
        return $pageURL;
    }
```

- Can anybody explain why?
- Is it forbidden to access array index directly by function's return value? If so, Why did it **worked at my localhost, but not at my live host**?

Comment: It should work in 5.4

Comment: yeah my hoster is at php 5.3 - that explains it all and one hour wasted time :/ thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$pageUrl = explode('?',curPageURL())[0];` only available when **php version >= 5.4**

> As of PHP 5.4 it is possible to array dereference the result of a
>   function or method call directly. Before it was only possible using a
>   temporary variable.

Your online host is below that version.

Answer (score 4):

You would need `current()` until you have PHP 5.4 that supports [array dereferencing on function results](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-88).

```
$pageUrl = current(explode('?',curPageURL()));
```